# What is the functionality of this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am recently learning regex and i am not quite sure how the following regex works:

```
str.replaceAll("(\\w)(\\w*)", "$2$1ay");
```

This allows us to do the following:

```
input string: "Hello World !"
return string: "elloHay orldWay !"
```

From what I know: w is supposed to match all word characters including 0-9 and underscore and $ matches stuff at the end of string.

Comment: Apart from reading the proposed duplicate, try inserting the text and regex into a site like https://regex101.com to see an explanation of what it is doing.

Comment: The return string is not because of the regex but because of the `replaceAll` method. It matches on every word that matches that regex and changes it to the second parameter.

Comment: See the explanation at https://regex101.com/r/clWQp1/1

Answer (score 0):

In the `replaceAll` method, the first parameter can be a regex. It matches all words in the string with the regex and changes them to the second parameter.

In simple cases replaceAll works like this:

```
str = "I,am,a,person"
str.replaceAll(",", " ") // I am a person
```

It matched all the commas and replaced them with a space.

In your case, the match is every alphabetic character(\w), followed by a stream of alphabetic characters(\w*).

The `()` around `\w` is to group them. So you have two groups, the first letter and the remaining part. If you use regex101 or some similar website you can see a visualization of this.

Your replacement is `$2` -> Second group, followed by $1(remaining part), followed by `ay`.

Hope this clears it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing a regex expression in brackets `()` will make it a Capturing group. 

Here you have 2 capturing groups , (\w) captures a single word character, and (\w*) catches zero or more.
$1 and $2 are used to refer to the captured groups, first and second respectively.

Also `replaceAll` takes each word individually.
So in this example in  'Hello' , 'H' is the first captured groups and 'ello' is the second. It's replaced by a reordered version - $2$1 which is basically swapping the captured groups.
So you get '$2$1ay' as 'elloHay'

The same for the next word also.